# Give a ForeignKey Form Field a value of a Queryset

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-class-based-views, keyword-argument

So I have two Models that I want to relate with a ForeignKey. One of the ModelForms I want to have it's Foreign Key field pre populated before the model gets created. The info from the ForeignKey comes from a ListView (List of Cars that belong to clients) template.

```
MODELS.PY

class ClientCar(models.Model):
    license_plate = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, name='license_plate')    

    def__str__:
        pk = self.pk
        license_plate = self.license_plate
        return f"pk:{pk} license_plate {license_plate}"

class CarDetail(model.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(ClientCar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
```

So the ListView template will have the basic crud of the Car model but I also want to add a "Wash button", the wash button will pass the selected Car's pk to the CarDetail Form template. It is here where I am having issues. I can Query the PK of the car from Kwargs but I can't seem to populate the Form's field with that query or have it render on the template.

```
VIEWS.PY

class WashService(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = CarDetail
    form_class = WashServiceForm
    template_name = 'service_app/standard_wash_form.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(WashService, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        ctd = ClientCar.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).values('license_plate')
        kwargs['initial']['car'] = ctd

        return kwargs
```

I have researched this and came to the understanding that in the Form for creating this model I have to overwrite the _ _ init _ _ function, I'm not really sure how to solve this since I don't know how to call the kwargs passed from the Listview template from the forms.py
 If you can guide me with some snippets or anything I'm greatful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to simply change what function the `ModelChoiceField` uses for the choices. We can first make a subclass of `ModelChoiceField` for the car, to select this by license plate:

```
from django import forms

class CarByLicensePlateChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.license_plate
```

Then in your `WashServiceForm` we can use this field:

```
class WashServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    car = CarByLicensePlateChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['car', 'detail']
```

In your `CreateView`, you can then populate the car with the `Car` that belongs to the given primary key:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class WashService(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = CarDetail
    form_class = WashServiceForm
    template_name = 'service_app/standard_wash_form.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        initials = kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})
        intial['car'] = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return kwargs
```

Comment: hey thanks for guiding me. But it only rendered a drop down button with a list of all the ClientCar objects. Thanks you for helping out anyways.